# Steps for adding a new device in a Linux operating system without requiring recompiling the kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, linux-device-driver, device-driver

I am trying to learn/understand the steps involved (from an operating system perspective) how a device can be added to a Linux operating system, without having to recompile the kernel. 
My understanding so far is that:

Linux operating systems contain a table, called the device table, which is indexed according to the number of devices. Each device is represented in the table by a device data structure; for each entry in the table, there is a pointer for all functions of the device. These pointers maintain the entry for read, write, open, close, etc, so that entries can be updated, added, and removed. 
When a new device is added and installed on the operating system, a new entry is made in the table. Then, pointers are filled in for the drivers of the new device.

However, in terms of the total actions of the operating system in implemeting this task, I know that there is a lot missing. However, I am having trouble finding more information about it online. Most search results using these terms just return instructions for installing a new hard drive. 
If anyone could give more of a step by step explanation of the process, I would really appreciate it.
Additionally, if any of the information I wrote earlier is incorrect, please let me know. I'm trying to make sure my understanding is correct and complete. Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: You can try to find some useful information [here](https://github.com/EbookFoundation/free-programming-books/blob/master/free-programming-books.md#linux) (but this is not about just the **kernel**, so not all of it applies). I have heard about [this book](https://www.gitbook.com/book/0xax/linux-insides/details). Its author is studying the Linux kernel design and writes notes. I can't guarantee it is accurate in all aspects, but it seems to contain huge amount of details.

Comment: You are trying to understand things from `from an operating system perspective`, but how `without requiring recompiling the kernel` correlates with that? Recompiling the kernel is not what OS does. So, which steps you are interested in? Ones, performed by operating system itself, or ones performed by the user? What kind of "device" do you mean? Character device, block device(e.g. hard drive), there are plenty of others device's types. Current question seems **unclear** for me. Also, "step by step explanations" smells as **too broad** for Stack Overflow format.

Comment: Oh okay, I'm sorry. The question was from a concept check my professor for and Operating Systems class put in a slide, that I realized I didn't know the concept behind. It simply read: What are the steps for adding a new device in a Linux operating system without requiring recompiling the kernel?

Comment: For character devices see https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.14-rc1/fs/char_dev.c#L249-L302